# CosmosDb unexpected continuation token

Tags: azure, pagination, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

**Please note:**

- I beleive this question is different than the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853612/null-continuation-token-in-cosmosdb) talking about why the continuation token is null. The problem listed here is about discussing this unexpected behaviour and see if there is any solution to it.
- I've also reported this on [cosmosdb github issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/692) because at this stage I think this could very well be an SDK or Cosmos API bug.

**Here it goes:**

Basically I am getting no result with a continuation token in an unexpected situation.

The only similar experience (no result but a continuation token) I had with CosmosDb was when the RU is not enough and the query needs more RU to finish its job. For example when counting all the documents and you need to continue couple of times.

**How to reproduce the issue?**

This is very hard to reproduce as the consumer does not control the shard (physical partition) distribution. But you need a comosdb that has a few logical partitions and at least two shards and your query should be formed aiming for the data in the second shared. Do not provide a partition key and make the query cross partition.

**Expected behavior**

When:

- the query is cross partition
- there is enough RU
- the query costs a very small RU

I'm expecting to receive the result in the first call.

**Actual behavior**

Query result is empty
Response has an unusual continuation token
The token looks like below:

> **{"token":null,"range":{"min":"05C1DFFFFFFFFC","max":"FF"}}**

Following is the sample code that I can reproduce the issue every single time. In this case I have a document sitting in partition 2 (index 1) which I assume it's the second shard.

```
var client = new DocumentClient(ServiceEndpoint, AuthKey);
const string query = "select * from c where c.title='JACK CALLAGHAN'";
var collection = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId);
var cQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(collection, query, new FeedOptions
{
    EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
    PopulateQueryMetrics = true
}).AsDocumentQuery();

var response = cQuery.ExecuteNextAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Console.WriteLine($"response.AsEnumerable().Count()= {response.AsEnumerable().Count()}");

foreach (string headerKey in response.ResponseHeaders.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{headerKey}");
    var keyValues = response.ResponseHeaders[headerKey].Split(";");
    foreach (var keyValue in keyValues)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{keyValue}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

And the output including all the headers:

```
response.AsEnumerable().Count()= 0
Cache-Control
no-store, no-cache

Pragma
no-cache

Transfer-Encoding
chunked

Server
Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

Strict-Transport-Security
max-age=31536000

x-ms-last-state-change-utc
Wed, 03 Apr 2019 00:50:35.469 GMT

x-ms-resource-quota
documentSize=51200
documentsSize=52428800
documentsCount=-1
collectionSize=52428800

x-ms-resource-usage
documentSize=184
documentsSize=164076
documentsCount=94186
collectionSize=188910

lsn
118852

x-ms-item-count
0

x-ms-schemaversion
1.7

x-ms-alt-content-path
dbs/bettingedge/colls/fixtures

x-ms-content-path
S8sXAPPiCdc=

x-ms-xp-role
1

x-ms-documentdb-query-metrics
totalExecutionTimeInMs=0.27
queryCompileTimeInMs=0.04
queryLogicalPlanBuildTimeInMs=0.02
queryPhysicalPlanBuildTimeInMs=0.03
queryOptimizationTimeInMs=0.00
VMExecutionTimeInMs=0.06
indexLookupTimeInMs=0.05
documentLoadTimeInMs=0.00
systemFunctionExecuteTimeInMs=0.00
userFunctionExecuteTimeInMs=0.00
retrievedDocumentCount=0
retrievedDocumentSize=0
outputDocumentCount=0
outputDocumentSize=49
writeOutputTimeInMs=0.00
indexUtilizationRatio=0.00

x-ms-global-Committed-lsn
118851

x-ms-number-of-read-regions
0

x-ms-transport-request-id
12

x-ms-cosmos-llsn
118852

x-ms-session-token
0:-1#118852

x-ms-request-charge
2.86

x-ms-serviceversion
version=2.2.0.0

x-ms-activity-id
c4bc4b76-47c2-42e9-868a-9ecfe0936b1e

x-ms-continuation
{"token":null,"range":{"min":"05C1DFFFFFFFFC","max":"FF"}}

x-ms-gatewayversion
version=2.2.0.0

Date
Fri, 05 Apr 2019 05:40:21 GMT

Content-Type
application/json
```

If we continue the query with the composite continuation token we can see the result.

Is that a normal behavior or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Using .NET Framework will handle continuation token natively:

`var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId,collectionI,
sqlQuery,feedOptions).AsDocumentQuery();

while (query.HasMoreResults)

{var response = await query.ExecuteNextAsync();
             results.AddRange(response);}`

Adding Feedback provided through linked [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/692):

Regarding your issues we have faced the same situations.
I have some comments.

> we didn't know about this behavior and our client received an empty list with a continuation token and pretty much broke our flow.
>
> Now in server side we are handling this situation and continue until we get result. The issue is what if there are 1000 partitions. Do we have to continue 100 times? Is that how ComosDB protect their SLA and under 10 ms response time. $ThinkingLoud

Yes, this broke our flow the first time too. But we handle it on the server side as well (Together with MaxNumberOfObjects we continue to serve request until we receive the number the client wants), and the pattern you're seeing is due to the underlying architecture of CosmosDB, consisting of phyiscal + logical partitions. It sounds like you're implementing Paging with the interplay of your client, and that is fine. However, I don't think this is what CosmosDB refer to with their SLA times.

> What other undocumented unexpected behaviors are there that are going to get us by surprise in production environment? #ThinkingLoudAgain

This is a bit vague, but my advice would be for you to read up on all FeedOptions together with CosmosDB Performance tips and make sure you understand them as well as their application areas.

EDIT: Also, another warning. I am currently running into an issue with Continuation Token and DISTINCT keyword in the SQL query. It does not work as expected without an ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior for CosmosDb. There are several things that can cause the query to timeout internally and result in a response with few results or even an empty collection.

From [CosmosDb documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-pagination):

> The number of items returned per query execution will always be less than or equal to MaxItemCount. However, it is possible that other criteria might have limited the number of results the query could return. If you execute the same query multiple times, the number of pages might not be constant. For example, if a query is throttled there may be fewer available results per page, which means the query will have additional pages. **In some cases, it is also possible that your query may return an empty page of results**.